# Positioning userform on the same monitor where excel is

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I'm creating a Dashboard in which when running Excel a userform is opened, maximized and Excel is hidden. My code works perfectly for a PC with just one monitor.

When using a dual-monitor PC VBA opens the userform on the main monitor, but to maximize it it takes the information from the monitor on which Excel was open.

Does anyone know how to make VBA identify on which monitor Excel is open and open the userform on that monitor?

```
'Set the Windows style so that the userform has a minimise and maximise button
lngCurrentStyle = GetWindowLong(lngHWnd, GWL_STYLE)
lngNewStyle = lngCurrentStyle Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX 'Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
lngNewStyle = lngNewStyle And Not WS_VISIBLE And Not WS_POPUP 'And WS_MINIMIZEBOX
SetWindowLong lngHWnd, GWL_STYLE, lngNewStyle

'Set the extended style to provide a taskbar icon
lngCurrentStyle = GetWindowLong(lngHWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
lngNewStyle = lngCurrentStyle Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW
SetWindowLong lngHWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lngNewStyle
ShowWindow lngHWnd, SW_SHOW

'Remove the top bar
HideTitleBar Me

'Maximize form
With Me
    .StartUpPosition = 1
    .Width = Application.Width
    .Height = Application.Height
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
End With
```

NOTE: I will not post the complete code here because it is not a very complex code, but long.

Thank you all.

Comment: Is your userform's `StartUpPosition` property set to 0? By default, the userform will open on whichever monitor you last had the editor open on. In my experience, positioning userforms where you want them is a complete and total pain.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 0, 1, 2 and 3... Always the same result. Yest it's a total pain!

Comment: What monitor is Excel on if I stretch its border across 2 monitors?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Whichever side has more of the window visible I guess :)